# Homology ring from Poincare duality?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Could we define homology ring via Poincare duality of cohomology ring?  If yes how should we identify the basis say for the following example in (12.11) Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture12.pdf)

$$H^*(BSO;\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}[p_1,p_2,\dots] \xrightarrow{D} H_*(BSO;\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}[p^1,p^2,\dots]$$

where the $p_i$'s are the Pontrjagin classes and the $p^i$'s their dual homology classes.

Comment: $BSO$ is not a finite dimensional manifold! You have no such duality! He's just using the universal coefficient theorem over a field. There's no ring structure here, it's just convenient to denote the vector space $H_*(BSO)$ that way.

Comment: @MikeMiller: so his "dual" really means universal coefficient theorem not Poincare duality even though we rarely use the word "dual" for the former?

Comment: Well, it certainly can't mean Poincare duality. It really is a duality here - the universal coefficient theorem for fields says that there is a natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(H_k(X;\Bbb F),\Bbb F) \to H^k(X;\Bbb F)$. AKA, cohomology is the dual vector space to homology.

Comment: @MikeMiller: got it!  That is clear now!  Sorry for the naive question!

Comment: Don't worry about it, your question was fine.